# Serialize Retrofit Call object

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I need to serialize a Retrofit Call instance to be executed in a later time.

Here is an example of a call:

```
Calls calls = NetworkHelper.getRetrofit().create(Calls.class);
Call<JsonResponse> call = calls.checkInAtEvent(user.getTokenID());
```

I need to serialize it and store in OrmLite so when the user opens the app again this call is executed.

The only way I thought of doing this is to store the method `checkInAtEvent` and the parameter `user.getTokenID()` in an object so I can identify the call and execute it. But, since I have several calls, I would need to use Reflect to instantiate the object for the given string name.

Is there a simpler way, maybe using OkHttp or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the point is to store a command that will be executed when the app is resumed.  The fact that it's a retrofit call is a side issue IMO.  I would just store a flag in `SharedPreferences` and check it on startup.  If it's there, do the call and remove the flag.  You can store any needed info like the ID along with it or as the value for the key-value pair.  If you have multiple different things you might need to do on startup, that can be handled too but maybe a little differently.